# Where should I put JDBC driver so that it works as part a Jax-rs webservice?

Tags: rest, jdbc, driver, jax-rs

I am building a RESTful web-service. I am using Jax-rs(Jersey), a simple client and a simple server. I have attached a PostgreSQL database and it's corresponding JDBC driver.

The server & client work perfectly when no database stuff is involved. (So the client/server code is fine)

Problems start When I augment the server to query the database: 
Server throws: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MyDataBase`
And the client reports a `500 internal service error`

If I utilize the database in an  identical manner from a plain old java application (in the same package), there are no problems whatsoever (so the connect/query code is also fine).

It's only when I query it from the server that I get the error. So, I gather that there's no problem with the code, only the location of the JDBC driver.

I've  tried:

- Putting the postgresql driver .jar just about  everywhere in my project
- Class.forName("../../..postgresql.jar")

I would like to know:

- Where is this .jar supposed to go in a dynamic web-project?
- Why does it work for java applications, but not from within an application server?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load the whole .jar file as a driver. You need to pick a Driver class from it.

```
Class.forName("../../..postgresql.jar")
```

The above code doesn't seem to be right.

Try this code instead:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
connection.close();
```

Comment: And there's no specific place to the .jar file. But make sure that it is in the classpath. And when you deploy the webapp, make sure that the .jar file is copied into the app's lib directory in the application server.